# Treat "Enter Query Title" and "Enter Query Description" same as missing in Titles and Tooltips when Browsing Queries

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Especially now that you have a default description filled in when a new query is created, when these have not been updated, you have no idea what they're doing until you follow the link.

The feature of displaying the actual SQL for the title or the tooltip is too useful to lose in these cases.

Comment: status-completed ... agree, it was getting out of control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a rather extensive change

1. I strip out initial comments from the tool tip
2. If the Default Enter Bla title is not touched it will not be saved as query name or description
3. I cleaned up all the historical queries and removed the bogus names

The list looks much better now

Comment: Can you get a final CR or two added to the default new query so you don't have to press return to just type SQL? I think it was like that before.